# Что такое юнит-тесты?

Tags: c, тестирование, юнит-тесты

Может кто-то объяснить принцип - как оно должно работать? Что такое тест для программы?
К примеру, есть задание: написать тест для программы, выводящей результат сложения двух введенных чисел.

Comment: Хороший тест - это набор данных, который выявляет ошибки в программе.
Например для сложения это два больших числа, а программа не сообщает о переполнении. Или на ввели не числа и программа аварийно завершилась.

Comment: slideshare.net/amritayan/test-driven-development-in-c

Comment: @VadimTukaev, будьте добры, не поднимайте древние (и тем более уже отвеченные) вопросы. Их авторы, скорее всего, не ждут ответов.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Я бы предложил вам выбрать стратегию тестирования, например, начать с простейших: черного и белого ящиков.

---

При использования метода **черного ящика** вы знаете то, что вам необходимо подать на вход, и соответственно, что вы получите на выходе для данного входа. А значит вы можете составлять тесты исходя из этих знаний.

Например для сложения чисел, у вас таблица из трех столбцов, первые два - входные значения, третий - результат. Проверяя по таблице работу вашей программы вы получите (в зависимости от количества проведенных тестов) % верных решений.

Обычно такие тесты называют системными (Sytem tests). Они более общие. Например, если у вас система из 5ти модулей, вы будете тестировать всю систему сразу, так как вы не знаете, что должно быть на входе и выходе любого из модулей, а знаете только общий результат.

---

При использовании метода **белого ящика** - вы знаете всю логику программы, так вы можете проверить каждую часть своей программы: операторы, условия, вводимые значения и т.п.

Обычно данный тип тестов называется юнит-тестом. Это тест, в котором вы проверяете работу не всей программы, а ее отдельных (атомарных в какой-то степени) частей.

Рассматривая предыдущий пример с 5ю модулями, вам известен вход и выход всех, вы можете тестировать каждый в отдельности или комбинировать их последовательность (заданную логикой программы, естественно).

Comment: Навеяно **белым ящиком**. Тестируя свою программу, постарайтесь, чтобы каждый оператор хоть раз в процессе прогона всех тестов отработал. Понятно, что исчерпывающее (для всех вариантов) тестирование невозможно, но каждая написанная строчка хоть раз должна выполниться.
На практике это очень сложно, поэтому начинайте тестировать написанные кусочки кода, как можно раньше.

Answer (score 3):

Тест, если говорить по-простому, это когда подаются в программу известные начальные данные (желательно качественно и количественно разные) и её ответ сравнивается с эталоном. То есть с тем, что должна выводить КОРРЕКТНО работающая программа.

Для такого простого случая она должна просто проверять правильность сложения. Задала числа, запустила тестируемую программу и проверила её ответ. Сошёлся - хорошо. Не сошёлся - программа работает неправильно.

Answer (score 3):

Кроме того, правильно написанная программа должна обрабатывать и ошибки ввода. Что произойдет если пользователь ввел только один аргумент? А если на вход поступило не число, а строка? А если программа не смогла запуститься из за нехватки ресурсов, например, оперативной памяти?

Правильно сформированный тест должен проверять не только штатную работу программу, но и её реакцию на нештатные ситуации.

Comment: ...так `print (a+b)` превратилось в 3 юнита и 1 библиотеку =)